# Error messages configuring php

Tags: apache, php

I downloaded PHP 5.4 to my computer which has Windows 8 (The customer preview), as there is no installer for 5.4 on Windows, i had to download the zip file that php.net offers. (I'm trying to install it to use for development), Now, I edited the php.ini but there was no place to tell php that my home directory is C:\Program files (x86)\PHP and I'm getting this error messages after starting apache:

```
[11-Apr-2012 18:54:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

By the way, I had to download the php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip from apachelounge because my apache is 2.4
Is there a way to correct this error messages? All i need to do is configure PHP to look for it's extensions in C:\Program files (x86)\PHP\ext

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program files (x86)\PHP\ext"
```

in your `php.ini`. To find out which one is loaded / where to find it, create a file called `info.php` with the following in it

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

and then browse to it, e.g. http://localhost/info.php

Comment: Great, it did work, now i'm only missing php_zip.dll and php_intl.dll which didn't came with my zip file for some reason.

Comment: You could download a fresh package from here: http://windows.php.net/download/ -- and just get the included extension DLL files you're missing from it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's no spaces in the folders names and try again

For instance:

install apache in C:\apache

install php in C:\php